# Pasar Json como parámetro

Tags: jquery, json

```
 [{"id":16819,"name":"1","mvt_a":51}, 
 {"id":16820,"name":"2","mvt_a":53}]
```

Este Json lo recibo haciendo una llamada al servidor mediante ajax.  (Tengo una variable  "Data" en ajax que contiene el json que vemos arriba.
Por cada fila del json tengo que hacer un boton y asignarlo a un div (Volcado).
Mi intención es que al hacer click sobre el botón que he creado, me rellene un formulario con los datos de su fila correspondiente.

Recorro primera fila del json, Creo el primer botón, y al hacer click sobre ese botón , llamar a una función pasandole la fila del json correspondiente

```
objJsonV = JSON.parse(data); //Data sería el Json qeu recibo del servidor
        $.each(objJsonV, function (i, item) {
           $(volcado).append("<button 
            type='button'onclick='ctr("Fila del Json correspondiente")' class='btn btn- 
            light'>"+ objJsonV[i].name +"</button>");
        });
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu lógica. ¿Dónde tiene el botón estos datos `[{"id":16819,"name":"1","mvt_a":51})` para pasarlos, o de dónde debe tomarlos? Tampoco se entiendes si el JSON que parseas y que muestras en el `each` es el mismo que contiene los datos que luego quieres enviar, ¿no sería eso marear demasiado los datos o es que no he comprendido el asunto?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he intentado explicarme un poco mejor editando la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahora se entiende mejor.

El problema que veo es que dentro del bucle intentas encontrar los valores haciendo referencia a `objJsonV`, cuando debes hacer referencia a `item`.

No sé si con esto: *`ctr("Fila del Json correspondiente")`*  quieres decir que quieres poner ahí el valor del índice de cada fila (he puesto eso en el código, pero puedes cambiarlo por otra propiedad del JSON). Ten en cuenta que si ahí te interesa el valor de `i` los arrays son indexados empezando por `0`, de modo que si quieres hacer coincidir ese dato con el del texto del botón, deberás poner algo así como `i + 1`, si observas la salida de consola, verás que los botones adquieren `ctr(0)` y  `ctr(1)` respectivamente.

De todos modos no queda claro a qué te refieres cuando hablas de *fila*.

Otra cosa es que no es bueno poner el `append` dentro del bucle. Cada vez que haces `append` el DOM se actualiza, así que es mejor concatenar una variable y hacer un sólo `append`, de ese modo el DOM no está constantemente actualizándose y consumiendo recursos innecesariamente.

```js
var data = `[{"id":16819,"name":"1","mvt_a":51}, 
 {"id":16820,"name":"2","mvt_a":53}]`;
var $volcado = $('#volcado');
var html = "";
objJsonV = JSON.parse(data); //Data sería el Json qeu recibo del servidor
$.each(objJsonV, function(i, item) {
  /* -------------------------
     Prueba de cada dato
  */
  console.log(item.id);
  console.log(item.name);
  console.log(item.mvt_a);
  /* ------------------------ */

  html += `<button type="button" onclick="ctr(${i})" class="btn btn- 
            light">${item.name}</button>`;
});
$(volcado).append(html);
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="volcado"></div>
```